# Unable to see image from resource drawable android with Log decoder->decode returned false

Tags: android, png, drawable

I have following drawable folder in my project .

drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi

Now i have put my splash png image in following folder

```
drawble-xxhdpi (1080x1920) 32-bit color png 
drawable-xhdpi  (720x1280) 24-bit color png 
drawable-hdpi    (540x960) 24 bit color png
```

Below is code of my xml file

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_splash"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
```

i am unable to understand why my image is not showing in splash screen 
i have also try decoding image but it giving me null bitmap :

```
 Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo_splash);
```

Below are log which xml file try to use image from resource :

```
 D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false
09-08 02:44:02.508  18909-18909/com.yyyy D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false
```

So any one known what could be issue for this .i am using android studio